# Django: Keeping the latest row for rows that have the same value in a column

Tags: python, django

So right now I have a table that is similar to:

| ID | NAME | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BOB | 2007 |
| 2 | BOB | 2007 |
| 3 | BOB | 2008 |

and I want to remove the first two and keep the third row.
I've tried using distinct() with order_by() with something like:

```
output = table.objects.all().order_by('NAME', '-Date').distinct('NAME')
```

but it only seems to remove one one of the first two rows. I am not using `PostgreSQL` unfortunately which is why I think the code above doesn't work as intended.